# Cannot instantiate chaincode for Fabric v 1.4.3

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

My chain code is written in Java and successfully installed on the fabric network.
But cannot be instantiated successfully, the log of the peer container is as below

```
2023-12-09 13:40:01.531 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 077 [mychannel][76f1a31c] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc" 
2023-12-09 13:40:04.945 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 078 [mychannel][76f1a31c] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (3413ms)
2023-12-09 13:40:04.945 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 079 [mychannel][76f1a31c] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: container exited with 1
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*RuntimeLauncher).Launch.func1
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/runtime_launcher.go:63
runtime.goexit
        /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
chaincode registration failed
2023-12-09 13:40:04.945 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 07a unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.30.0.13:51532 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=3.414032611s
```

How can I solve it?